# Unity Raycast says that there are not hits, but there clearly are. Having some issues getting this to work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

In the image you see how the `Raycast` goes straight through the object.

`RaycastHit` however returns no hits. In fact, on rare occasions it returns a hit, but it's rare. I'm guessing it has to do with `Update`/`FixedUpdate`/`LateUpdate`. Since it's camera work, I put my code in `LateUpdate`.

I tried the others just for kicks, and as expected, it has consistent `0` hits, and the `Raycast` misses the object ever single time.

Code goes like this, where `otherObject` is another specific object that is not the blue planet in the image:

```
bool IsOtherObjectHidingBehindThatBlueSphereInTheImage(...)
{
    Vector3 direction = otherObject - mainCamera.transform.position;
    Ray ray = new(mainCamera.transform.position, direction.normalized);

    Debug.DrawRay(mainCamera.transform.position, direction, Color.red);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit))
    {
        if (hit.transform != otherObject)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The Raycast to hit every single frame.

Comment: The blue sphere (planet) has a collider? and .. would just be a really weird case but it is also isn't on the layer `IgnoreRaycasts`?

Comment: 1. Layers. Check them, as @derHugo said. 2. Raycast distance. 3. ??? Not enough info in the original post. Looks like a vague emotional complain rather than a strong report with facts and data. I working with Unity professionally for years and tell you 100% its raycasting is reliable as rock if you're not dealing with extreme velocities or at the distances of significant floating point error.

Comment: derHugo, It has a collider, and it's not on the IgnoreRaycasts. As I stated, it does hit sometimes. :(

Comment: Xander, don't post if you're here to complain and not help. Thanks.

Comment: @SanyoHamarr are you also sure the displayed ray is not just passing in front of the sphere? With this kind of issues it is really hard to tell without having the project in front of you tbh ...

Comment: Of course I'm sure, @derHugo, I didn't just willy nilly made an assumption. I looked at it and tried to work it out. Issue unfortunately remains unresolved.